# convert NSMutableArray to CGPoint Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cgpoint

the typical answer will be "you can convert it to nsvalue and then use [element CGPointValue];
but in my case i need to generate array of type CGPoint , as i need it in a built in function below :

```
static CGPathRef createClosedPathWithPoints(const CGPoint *points, size_t count) {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddLines(path, NULL, points, count);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}
```

so , i need to pass the exact datatype , as i can't parse it element by element , or i need a way to everytime the user make a specific action , i add it's CGPoint to array of CGPoints :(( 
thanks in advance 
edit : 
i have tried malloc and making c array but the result of the function was not desirable , i tested and made infinity for loop to that malloc array , and it's too large not just like the size i sat , and contain garbage so the result went wrong

this is the mutable array

```
pointToPoints = [NSMutableArray new];
[pointToPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:tempPoint] ];
```

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to convert the `NSMutableArray` to the C array of `CGPoint`.

Comment: This is C. Do you know C? Do you know what a C array is?

Comment: did you see my talk about malloc ??

Comment: would you give sample of NSMutableArray

Comment: [pointToPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:tempPoint] ];

Comment: "did you see my talk" We saw your talk. What we didn't see is any code. Don't talk _about_ your code; show it.

Comment: it's a simple code , i edited

Comment: Do you just need the array for use with the `createClosedPathWithPoints ` function you provide?

Comment: yes , i am at way home now i will test your answer soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that will create a closed path from an `NSArray` of `NSValue` created with `CGPoint` using the code your provided:

```
BOOL isCGPoint(NSValue *value){
    return value && strcmp([value objCType], @encode(CGPoint)) == 0;
}

- (CGPathRef) closedPathFromPointArray:(NSArray *)points{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    if(points.count){
        CGPoint origin = ((NSValue *)points[0]).CGPointValue;
        CGPathMoveToPoint (path, NULL, origin.x, origin.y);

        // see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathAddLines
        for(NSValue *value in points){
            CGPathAddLineToPoint (path, NULL, value.CGPointValue.x, value.CGPointValue.y);
        }
    }

    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}
```

As you see, you don't really need malloc, or even creating a C array of `CGPoint`. This assumes you only need this array for creating the closed path.
Two extra things of note:

- See the commented link for [CGPathAddLines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathAddLines), as it describes how `CGPathAddLines` works internally. This gives you the hint about how to go about this.
- The `isCGPoint` function is included so you can test if a given `NSValue` instance was actually created using `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:]`. My previous answer checked this, but I thought it was ooverkill to check everywhere. In any case, it's included here for didactic purposes.

Comment: I fully edited my answer to something simpler and using Apple's documentation on `CGPathAddLines`

Comment: Interesting...  I thought he wanted an array of cgpoints as a result.

Comment: Yep, he did ask for that. Although he did say in comments that he only needed that for use with `CGPathAddLines`

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint *points = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint) * mutableArrayOfPoints.count);
for (int i = 0; i < mutableArrayOfPoints.count; i++) {
    points[i] = [mutableArrayOfPoints[i] pointValue];
}
```

The above is from memory.  I haven't used malloc() in ages, so you may need to adjust syntax.

Comment: if you try to make an infinity loop it wont break at the array.count 
i don't know why

Comment: This code needs a little work since you can't directly store `CGPoint` in the `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: If you try to make an infinite loop, of course it won't break at count.  Why would you expect it to?

I think you're not explaining yourself very well.